# Status of the Dothraki after "The Long Night"

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I know that my question is related to the question [Point of the Dothraki's attack](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99973/point-of-the-the-dothrakis-attack-in-got-s8e3). I'm posting a new question as I couldn't find my answer in [there](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99973/point-of-the-the-dothrakis-attack-in-got-s8e3).

In the *Game of Thrones* episode "The Long Night", when the Dothraki charged with their flame scythes they were slaughtered by the army of the dead and not a single Dothraki was shown in the later fight when the castle was breached.

Does this mean that our beloved Khaleesi lost all of her Dothraki hordes?

Comment: We clearly see some Dothraki retreat after the massacre so some will remain but since they are minor characters it's not surprising we don't see any in the rest of the episode...there was a lot to cover.

Comment: @Paulie_D how come there were no Dothraki women & children in the crypts. What happened to the Dosh Khaleen I wonder

Comment: Since it's an ongoing series, you should wait and watch the rest of it (there are only 3 more episodes after all). Otherwise all we can do is speculate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [theringer.com](https://www.theringer.com/game-of-thrones/2019/4/30/18523891/game-of-thrones-dothraki-battle-winterfell-daenerys-targaryen-long-night)

> “What [the other characters] see is the end of the Dothraki, essentially,” series cocreator David Benioff said in an Inside the Episode segment after the credits on Sunday night.

From Game of Thrones S08E04:

Tyrion mentioned about:

> "remaining Dothraki" for the upcoming war.

Also

> In the episodes [The Bells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bells_(Game_of_Thrones)) and [The Iron Throne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Throne_(Game_of_Thrones)), we see the Dany's army including the Dothraki fight against the Lannisters and after winning the battle they appear in Dany's speech. In the episode ending, we see the Dothraki civilians in the King's Landing's market.

So that's the status of the Dothraki.

Comment: Might be a few survivors. But we can clearly see that out of the massive army assembled, a lot of them died.

Comment: There are non-combative Dothraki still in the world, I expect - back in Vaes Dothrak or in the great grass sea, etc. But I recall Danerys essentially creating a horde of every male Dothraki of fighting age, so around 2 generations of male Dothraki destroyed and decades before any horde could be assembled again. The culture will probably survive, but maybe not some aspects such as fighting traditions.

Comment: I remember someone saying that there now is "half" of them in episode 4, the scene at the war table

Comment: @IvoBeckers They apparently lost half of everyone.  Northmen, Dothraki, Unsullied...  The army got Thanos'd.

Answer (score 2):

If you roughly count the number of Dothraki at the battle it would barely reach fifteen thousand. Supposedly one hundred thousand came across the sea, fighting men alone. Even if they all died at the battle, Daenerys still has a lot left. But I suppose they did not have the time and budget for a CGI Dothraki army nine times larger and that could be the hundred thousand represented. Undoubtedly at least a few thousand would have survived for plot reasons.